# How to crop the image using tensorflow lite after object detection in android

Tags: android, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

Not able to crop the image of the object which is detected by tensor flow lite.

I am using the ar.sceneform library to update the frame like this.

```
 private void onUpdateFrame(FrameTime frameTime) {
try {

            Frame frame = fragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
            cameraImage = frame.acquireCameraImage();

//The camera image received is in YUV YCbCr Format. Get buffers for each of the planes and use them to create a new bytearray defined by the size of all three buffers combined
            ByteBuffer cameraPlaneY = cameraImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            ByteBuffer cameraPlaneU = cameraImage.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer();
            ByteBuffer cameraPlaneV = cameraImage.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();

//Use the buffers to create a new byteArray that
            byte[] compositeByteArray = new byte[(cameraPlaneY.capacity() + cameraPlaneU.capacity() + cameraPlaneV.capacity())];

            cameraPlaneY.get(compositeByteArray, 0, cameraPlaneY.capacity());
            cameraPlaneU.get(compositeByteArray, cameraPlaneY.capacity(), cameraPlaneU.capacity());
            cameraPlaneV.get(compositeByteArray, cameraPlaneY.capacity() + cameraPlaneU.capacity(), cameraPlaneV.capacity());

            ByteArrayOutputStream baOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(compositeByteArray, ImageFormat.NV21, cameraImage.getWidth(), cameraImage.getHeight(), null);
            yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, cameraImage.getWidth(), cameraImage.getHeight()), 75, baOutputStream);
            byte[] byteForBitmap = baOutputStream.toByteArray();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteForBitmap, 0, byteForBitmap.length);
            imageViewResult.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            cameraImage.close();


                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, INPUT_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE, false);

                imageViewResult.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                final List<Classifier.Recognition> results = classifier.recognizeImage(bitmap);
                Log.d("resultsize", String.valueOf(results.size()));

            textViewResult.setText(String.valueOf(results));


        }catch (NotYetAvailableException e) {
            Log.e("erroroccur",e.toString());
        };
}
```

How to capture the image after getting the result of List and compare the object probability if it is greater then 80 % then return the cropped object image.

Comment: You should [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58735381/edit) your post with what you've tried and what isn't working along with the code you are using.

Comment: thanks @MorrisonChang, I have update my question with used source code. please help me out.